# Symfony constraint validation not working, groups ignored

Tags: symfony, validation

Ive tried creating my validator but it does not work.
Documentation does not help because it only cares for object validation and has one example for array validation.

Im trying to validate my data based on fields sent with the data.
So im having a field `type` in the request which is either `credentials`, `google` or `facebook` and depending on this fields value the other fields should be validated.
Of course the `type` has to be validated first.

What I tried was following the documentation for collections but I only get unexpected Exceptions and results. Sometimes errors, sometimes dont, the thing just does not work as expected.

Given the following example:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;

require_once(__DIR__ . "/../vendor/autoload.php");

$validator = Validation::createValidator();

$constraints = new Assert\Collection([
    "type" => [
        new Assert\Required([
            "groups" => ["type"],
            "constraints" => new Assert\Choice([
                "choices" => ["credentials", "facebook", "google"],
            ])
        ]),
    ],
    "username" => [
        new Assert\NotBlank([
            "groups" => ["credentials", "facebook", "google"]
        ])
    ],
    "password" => [
        new Assert\NotBlank([
            "groups" => ["credentials"]
        ]),
        new Assert\Length([
            "min" => 6,
            "groups" => ["credentials"]
        ]),
    ],
    "passwordConfirm" => [
        new Assert\NotBlank([
            "groups" => ["credentials"],
        ]),
        new Assert\IdenticalTo([
            "groups" => ["credentials"],
            "propertyPath" => "password"
        ])
    ]
]);

$data = [];

$errors = $validator->validate($data, $constraints, "credentials");


foreach ($errors as $error) {
    echo $error->getPropertyPath() . ": " . $error->getMessage() . "<br />";
}
```

Will output:

```
[type]: This field is missing.
[username]: This field is missing.
[password]: This field is missing.
[passwordConfirm]: This field is missing.
```

Even though I have explicitly passed `"credentials"` to groups.
Ive also tried using the `fields` option but it introducec more problems.
Does anyone know how to use the validator properly and use groups to actually only validate subsets of data.

Answer (score 0):

why are you using `Assert\Collection`? that's useful to validate an array of similar objects/items

I think you should just substitute: `$constraints = new Assert\Collection([` with `$constraints = [`, as to say you should use a plain array of constraints

Comment: Because this is how it is described in the documentation. I have to use Collection because I have to validate the key/values and not the array itself.

Comment: Collection is to handle an array of arrays basically, or array of objects and it doesn't seem your case

Comment: can you paste a link to the doc?

Comment: [Symfony - How to Validate Raw Values (Scalar Values and Arrays)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/raw_values.html)

Comment: anyway I saw that `$data = [];` is an empty array, it's right that the errors you have are `This field is missing `, because you didn't submit any data

Comment: if you passed `$data = ['username' => '']` for example, your validation should give expected results

Comment: thats not the issue, type shouldnt be included in the error because i only validate credentials group. But the documentation sucks, so I switched to class validation.